# how to use the last id SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to the android world and have a problem with an id. What i need is that when the user clicks on new match it will insert a new row into the db. This is working and i get the lastId but now i need this id in the next activities. How can i store that id so i can use it elsewhere?

This is how i insert the new match:

```
public void newMatch(WedstrijdenGeschiedenis wedstrijd){

// 1. 
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

// 2. 
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_DATUM, dateFormat.format(date)); // get datum 

// 3. 
long lastId = db.insert(TABLE_WEDSTRIJD, // table
null, //nullColumnHack
values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values
Log.d("New Match","ID ="+lastId);

// 4. close
db.close(); 

}
```

so i see the lastId in LogCat but i don't know how to store it for further use. I tried void but offcourse that is not possible on void. Sorry for the dummy question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The id you get back on `lastId` is the id that was automatically created as your primary key for that record. It is already stored in the database.

Comment: Why? The database knows that id and if you insert from another activity it will still know it and use another id (usually just 1 higher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `void` to `long` and add a return statement that returns the lastId

```
public long newMatch(WedstrijdenGeschiedenis wedstrijd){
  // Your other code
  return lastId;
}
```

Access it with:

```
long lastId= db.newMatch(new WedstrijdenGeschiedenis());
```

Comment: In my activity i do this: 
        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        db.newMatch(new WedstrijdenGeschiedenis());
So how do i get the id there?

Comment: yes it is. sorry for my ignorance and thank you for your help! This is what i needed